# Certificate/Criterion for the existence of zero of a complex multivariate polynomial in a bounded region

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables

I have a polynomial $f\in\mathbb{C}[X_1,...X_n]$ and a bounded (non-empty) compact region $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}^n$. Let's say additionally that $f$ is not zero on the boundary of $\Omega$.
Does there exist a certificate/criterion, which tells me whether there exists an $a\in\Omega$ such that $f(a)=0$?

I think for the univariate case, one could apply the [Argument Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle).

Comment: your use of the word 'certificate' leads me to think you might be interested in numerical solutions to your problem.  If so, 'Bertini' might be what you want.

Comment: @aginensky I know Bertini, but I thought that there is maybe a more efficient way since I don't need the actual root.

Comment: Maybe stupid but I think if $f$ is nonzero on the boundary then it must also be nonzero in the interior. The zero set is a hyper surface, no isolated zeros...?

Comment: When you say that $f$ is not zero on the boundary of $\Omega$, do you mean that $f(p) \neq 0$ for all $p \in \partial \Omega$, or do you just mean that $f$ is not identically zero on $\partial \Omega$? (I think $f$ can't be identically zero on $\partial \Omega$ anyway, unless $f$ is the zero polynomial; or unless I'm overlooking something...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I think Zach is right, though you need a little more care. Since $\partial\Omega$ is not algebraic, it is not entirely straightforward that any hypersurface should intersect it, so one would need a version of the Jordan–Brouwer separation theorem to conclude that if there is a zero inside, then there has to be one on the boundary as well. This would boil down to analyzing the shape of $\Omega$, which could probably be made nice using the fact that $f$ is a polynomial.  On the other hand, here is an alternative argument which shows that $f$ doesn't even have to be a polynomial. If it is holomorphic everywhere in $\Omega$, that's enough.

First, the multivariate case:

Just to make sure, let us assume that  $\partial\Omega$ is connected. It seems to me that one can reduce to this case (especially if we are dealing with a polynomial), but sometimes these "simple" topological issues take a long time to sort out, so let me leave this to the reader.

> > **Claim.** Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on $\Omega$ (whose boundary is connected). 
> >     If $n\geq 2$ and $\forall z\in\partial\Omega$, $f(z)\neq 0$, then $\forall z\in\Omega$, $f(z)\neq 0$.

**Proof:** Let $g=\dfrac 1f$. Then $g$ is a holomorphic function in a neighbourhood of $\partial\Omega$, so by Hartogs' theorem it admits a holomorphic extension to $\Omega$ which we will also denote by $g$. So, $g$ and $f$ are two holomorphic functions on $\Omega$ and $fg=1$, so neither can have a zero in $\Omega$. $\square$

OK, so this leaves the $n=1$ case, which is indeed settled by the Argument Principle as you suggest. (Since $f$ is holomorphic inside $\Omega$, it cannot have a pole, so the integral that appears in the Argument Principle would be non-zero exactly if $f$ had a zero.)

Comment: One question regarding your proof. I don't see exactly, why $fg=1$ should hold in $\Omega$. Why can it not happen that $g$ (the extension) differs from $1/f$ in $\Omega$?

Comment: I thought this would be obvious. The holomorphic function $fg-1$ is zero on a non-empty open set (the neighbourhood of $\partial\Omega$ where $f\neq 0$) and hence it is zero everywhere. This can be proven a number of ways. For instance, the zero set of a not identically zero holomorphic function has measure zero. Or, take a general (complex-)line that intersects $\Omega$ non-trivially and restrict there. Then $fg-1$ could only have isolated zeros on this line if it weren't zero everywhere.